# Mac OS shortcut for opening new instance of app

Tags: macos

In Windows i can open a new instance of an app that is already running by holding shift and clicking the app in the "dock". On MacOS i'd have to open the terminal and run "open -n path_to_the_app". Is it possible to fix that somehow so i can use the shift-key to open a new instance of an already open app?

Answer (score 1):

You can also open an application by name with `open -na name` (where the name can be all lowercase).

If you use Alfred, you can create an action for opening a new instance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click the icon in the dock and then choose `New window`.